# Child Trigger event on parent Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent, children

I am making a game in Unity3D and I have this situation.

I have a parent with some children. Eg:

Parent:

- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3

On Parent and Child 3 i have the component Box Collider 2D with the property Is Trigger checked.

On the parent i have a script with OnTriggerEnter2D function

But if Child 3 collide with another object it trigger the function on the parent's script.

I don't need to trigger the event when the Child collide.

What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting a kinematic rigidbody on the child.